# Angular routing- Apply is missing in type 'ModuleWithProviders<RouterModule>'

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

This is my app.module.ts code for routing

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule,Routes, ROUTES} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import {DepartmentListComponent} from './department-list/department-list.component';
import {EmployeeListComponent} from './employee-list/employee-list.component';
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'department', component: DepartmentListComponent },
  { path: 'employee',      component: EmployeeListComponent },

];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
         path: 'new-cmp',
         component: EmployeeListComponent
      }
   ])    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but i got following error.

[ts]
Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type'.
  Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'Type'.
    Property 'apply' is missing in type 'ModuleWithProviders'.
(property) Route.component?: Type

Comment: Have you tried this : `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)` instead of `RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
         path: 'new-cmp',
         component: EmployeeListComponent
      }
   ])`

Comment: @ShashikantDevani i have tried but same error

Answer (score 1):

You need to import RouterModule package in imports. e,g, below

imports: [
    BrowserModule,RouterModule 
  ],